# ruby on rails rake db:migrate rake aborted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

when running `rake db:migrate` i get this error message:

```
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::ReadOnlyException: attempt to write a readonly database: CREATE TABLE "schema_migrations" ("version" varchar NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/statement.rb:108:in `step'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/statement.rb:108:in `block in each'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/statement.rb:107:in `loop'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/statement.rb:107:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:152:in `map'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:152:in `block in execute'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:95:in `prepare'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:137:in `execute'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:255:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:48:in `block in permit_concurrent_loads'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:187:in `yield_shares'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:47:in `permit_concurrent_loads'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:254:in `block in execute'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:579:in `block (2 levels) in log'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:578:in `block in log'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:23:in `instrument'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:569:in `log'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:253:in `execute'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:311:in `create_table'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/schema_migration.rb:29:in `create_table'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1187:in `initialize'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1036:in `new'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1036:in `up'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1011:in `migrate'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:172:in `migrate'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:60:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'

Caused by:
SQLite3::ReadOnlyException: attempt to write a readonly database
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/statement.rb:108:in `step'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/statement.rb:108:in `block in each'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/statement.rb:107:in `loop'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/statement.rb:107:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:152:in `map'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:152:in `block in execute'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:95:in `prepare'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:137:in `execute'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:255:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:48:in `block in permit_concurrent_loads'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:187:in `yield_shares'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:47:in `permit_concurrent_loads'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:254:in `block in execute'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:579:in `block (2 levels) in log'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:578:in `block in log'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:23:in `instrument'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:569:in `log'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:253:in `execute'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:311:in `create_table'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/schema_migration.rb:29:in `create_table'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1187:in `initialize'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1036:in `new'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1036:in `up'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1011:in `migrate'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:172:in `migrate'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:60:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

this is the result of `ls -l`:

```
total 72
drwxrwxrwx 10 root root 4096 Jun  3 14:23 app
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root 4096 Jun  3 14:24 bin
drwxrwxrwx  5 root root 4096 Jun  3 14:23 config
-rw-rw-rw-  1 root root  130 Jun  3 14:23 config.ru
drwxrwxrwx  3 root root 4096 Jun  3 23:47 db
-rw-rw-rw-  1 root root 2205 Jun  3 14:23 Gemfile
-rw-rw-rw-  1 root root 5295 Jun  3 14:24 Gemfile.lock
drwxrwxrwx  4 root root 4096 Jun  3 14:23 lib
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root 4096 Jun  3 14:28 log
-rw-rw-rw-  1 root root   66 Jun  3 14:23 package.json
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root 4096 Jun  3 14:23 public
-rw-rw-rw-  1 root root  227 Jun  3 14:23 Rakefile
-rw-rw-rw-  1 root root  374 Jun  3 14:23 README.md
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root 4096 Jun  3 14:23 storage
drwxrwxrwx  9 root root 4096 Jun  3 14:23 test
drwxrwxrwx  6 root root 4096 Jun  3 14:42 tmp
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root 4096 Jun  3 14:23 vendor
```

this is the result of running the original command suffixed with `--trace`:

```
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::ReadOnlyException: attempt to write a readonly database: CREATE TABLE "schema_migrations" ("version" varchar NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/statement.rb:108:in `step'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/statement.rb:108:in `block in each'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/statement.rb:107:in `loop'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/statement.rb:107:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:152:in `map'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:152:in `block in execute'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:95:in `prepare'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:137:in `execute'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:255:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:48:in `block in permit_concurrent_loads'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:187:in `yield_shares'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:47:in `permit_concurrent_loads'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:254:in `block in execute'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:579:in `block (2 levels) in log'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:578:in `block in log'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:23:in `instrument'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:569:in `log'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:253:in `execute'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:311:in `create_table'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/schema_migration.rb:29:in `create_table'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1187:in `initialize'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1036:in `new'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1036:in `up'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1011:in `migrate'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:172:in `migrate'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:60:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:271:in `block in execute'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:271:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:271:in `execute'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:213:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:193:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:182:in `invoke'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `invoke_task'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block in top_level'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:125:in `run_with_threads'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `top_level'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:83:in `block in run'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'

Caused by:
SQLite3::ReadOnlyException: attempt to write a readonly database
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/statement.rb:108:in `step'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/statement.rb:108:in `block in each'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/statement.rb:107:in `loop'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/statement.rb:107:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:152:in `map'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:152:in `block in execute'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:95:in `prepare'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:137:in `execute'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:255:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:48:in `block in permit_concurrent_loads'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:187:in `yield_shares'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:47:in `permit_concurrent_loads'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:254:in `block in execute'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:579:in `block (2 levels) in log'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:578:in `block in log'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:23:in `instrument'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:569:in `log'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:253:in `execute'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:311:in `create_table'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/schema_migration.rb:29:in `create_table'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1187:in `initialize'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1036:in `new'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1036:in `up'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1011:in `migrate'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:172:in `migrate'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:60:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:271:in `block in execute'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:271:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:271:in `execute'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:213:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:193:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:182:in `invoke'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `invoke_task'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block in top_level'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:125:in `run_with_threads'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `top_level'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:83:in `block in run'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

my database.yml file:

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
#
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.sqlite3
```

again with the code to text ratio:

dfgdfghd fghdfg hdfghdgh dfghdfgh dfghdfghd fgghdfghdf hdghdfg hdfgghdf ghdfghdf hdfghdf ghdfghd fghdf ghdfg h dfghdfg h dfgh  dfgh dghdfgf hdfgh fgdfgfhdfg hdfgh fghdf ghdfg dfghd fhdf ghdf hdfg hdghdf ghdfgh dghdfgh dfgndfn fgndf gndfgn dfgfn df ndfg ndg ndfg dg n dfg n dfgndfgndf gndfg ndfgnfg hdf ghdfh gfndfgh dfghdf gdfgh dfgh hdfh dfghdf ghdfg hfg hdfg hdf g

output of `ls -l` in db directory:

```
total 8
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Jun  3 14:42 development.sqlite3
drwxrwxr-x 2 jack jack 4096 Jun  3 23:47 migrate
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root  370 Jun  3 14:23 seeds.rb
```

Comment: Include your database.yml in your post (with any passwords redacted).

Comment: and also `ls -l` the db directory itself, nevause your sqlite is there, or is it actually there?

Comment: i havent moved it there so it shouldnt be

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 6):

Your database is owned by root, and only root has write access. I'm betting you're running your app as the jack user, so you don't have write access.

Did you create this repo using the sudo command? (sudo rails new or whatever). Your whole app is owned by root.

```
cd [your app's main directory]
chown -R jack:jack .
```

Comment: would he be able to even start it if it was the other user?

Comment: Theoretically yes, but running as root isn't typically ideal. The `database.yml` is pretty stock. The only thing that jumps out at me is that the file is owned by root and the permissions are for root (read/write) and everyone else read-only. Often weird errors like this have little to do with the Rails stack and more to do with a system config error. In this case, the culprit is that the app was generated as root (likely with a `sudo rails` command), and I'd bet he's running as jack.

Comment: i created it as root but changed the permissions after, i can edit the files without providing a password but the scripts cant

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the directory containing the database file is also writable to the user executing the CGI script

ref: [Change SQLite database mode to read-write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518729/change-sqlite-database-mode-to-read-write)